# What is a start_color and end_color in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm now working on a script that parse xlsx files using python 3 and openpyxl.
And I'm confused with the color things.

What is a start_color and end_color of a cell?

I've searched the document but no information was about this.

I can access them with cell.style.fill.start_color, and they give me colors like 'FFFF0000'.

But what do start_color and end_color mean?
Why do I need 2 to fill a cell?

Comment: These are used in colour gradients.